# How to show product price in home page

Tags: product, magento-1, price

I installed my site and in theme that i use it for my website in home page i can show latest product but without price and i want to show price of each product in home page.

So i want to know what steps i should take to do this?

What things i should know for this? Should i know about writing modules?

Please tell me about the steps that i should take for it.

Comment: please show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>` in new.phtml file in template/catalog/product section.

Comment: copy this code where? which line of this page i should copy this code?

Comment: add below image.. you can use firebug, an addon provided by firefox to bug frontend..

Comment: yesssssss, thank you soooooo much, also i want to add buy basket below the price how can i do this? and also i don't know that this code of this page do it, do you know any tutorial about pages of Magento that what these pages do?

Comment: telling one by one wont do.. i suggest to check in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\new.phtml file so you get an idea.. there you could find desired codes..

Comment: if you got answer, please accept and up vote so it will help others..Thanks..

Comment: Glad it worked. And...welcome to SE. When an answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted. This way it helps future readers as well

Answer (score 0):

You can display New product From Widgets.

- Go to admin->CMS->Widgets and add new Widgets here.
- Click New Widget Instance.
- Now select Type -Catalog New Product List
- Design Package/Theme *   -Your theme
- Now Click On Continue

You will find here Layout Updates option here  Display On Specific Page    ,Page-CMS HOme Page Block Reference.

Choose here which column you want to display.

Now Go to admin->catalog->Manage Products and edit some products and set attribute date Set "Product as New from Date" and "Set Product as New to Date".

Now refresh Cache and indexing you will find here new product with price ,wishlist,compare  ...etc.

Comment: really thanks for your answer, i have a carousel list in home page that it show latest product with it's name and image and i just want to add price for each image, do you know a solution for this? your way is so good but if i use this widget i should edit style of this widget and it takes too much time.

Comment: You can get price in simple way <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>  ,if this is not giving then you need to share code.